# Pandas Filling Missing Values Down Based on Row Above

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
data={'col1':[1,3,3,1,2,3,2,2, 1], 'col2':[np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['col1', 'col2'])
print df

   col1  col2
0     1   NaN
1     3   1.0
2     3   NaN
3     1   1.0
4     2   NaN
5     3   NaN
6     2   NaN
7     2   2.0
8     1   NaN
```

I am trying to make a third column that fills in the NaN vales in `col2` if the value of `col2` is equal to `1.0` or the row above in `col2` is `1.0`.  The final dataframe would look like this:

```
 col1  col2  col3
0     1   NaN   NaN
1     3   1.0   1.0
2     3   NaN   1.0
3     1   1.0   1.0
4     2   NaN   1.0
5     3   NaN   1.0
6     2   NaN   1.0
7     2   2.0   2.0
8     1   NaN   NaN
```

First approach I tried was:

`df['col3'] = ((df['col2']== 1) | ((df['col2'].shift()== 1))).astype('int')`

This leaves me with this dataframe:

```
col1  col2  col3
0     1   NaN     0
1     3   1.0     1
2     3   NaN     1
3     1   1.0     1
4     2   NaN     1
5     3   NaN     0
6     2   NaN     0
7     2   2.0     0
8     1   NaN     0
```

Which corrects the first instance of a missing value, but does not continue to fill missing values.  I also tried using the `np.where()` function and I get the same results.

Is there a way to write this in pandas where it fixes multiple instances in a row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) by looking at where the forward-fill is equal to one, filling 1 where it's True, and falling back to the value of 'col2' when it's False:

```
df['col2'] = np.where(df['col2'].ffill() == 1, 1, df['col2'])
```

The resulting output:

```
   col1  col2
0     1   NaN
1     3   1.0
2     3   1.0
3     1   1.0
4     2   1.0
5     3   1.0
6     2   1.0
7     2   2.0
8     1   NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the *df.fillna* function with forward padding like this:

```
df.fillna(method='pad')

   col1  col2
0     1   NaN
1     3   1.0
2     3   1.0
3     1   1.0
4     2   1.0
5     3   1.0
6     2   1.0
7     2   2.0
8     1   2.0
```

Comment: I only want to fill in the values if col2 is 1.0 or the row above is 1.0 -  your suggestion also fills in the missing value where the row above is 2.0

Comment: Sorry I missed that detail. The other answers work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

```
ffilled = df.col2.ffill()
df.assign(col3=df.col2.fillna(ffilled[ffilled == 1]))
```