# How do I fill NaNs with the result of another matching row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the format

```
USER | ADDRESS | PURCHASE
1    | add 1   |  A
1    | NaN     |  B
2    | NaN     |  C
2    | add 2   |  D
3    | NaN     |  E
```

For User 1, I want to fill the ADDRESS in the NaN row with add 1, and I want to do the same for User 2 for the NaN row. I don't want to group by, and I want to keep the 4 row format. Just want to fill in the NAN address. For User 3, who doesn't have a match, I want to leave it as NaN.

I've tried doing a groupby user, but that ends up filling everything and putting everything together which is not what I want

No code

I just want to fill in the addresses for each user accordingly

Comment: If your list is sorted by user id, this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42447598/pandas-filling-missing-values-down-based-on-row-above

Comment: try `df['ADDRESS'] = df['ADDRESS'].ffill()`

Comment: What happens if a `user` has multiple addresses? Do those need to be filled in any particular way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what is the issue with grouping but when you want to fill missing values "by group", you need to use groupby

```
df['ADDRESS'] = df.groupby('USER').ADDRESS.apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())

   USER ADDRESS PURCHASE
0   1   add 1   A
1   1   add 1   B
2   2   add 2   C
3   2   add 2   D
4   3   NaN     E
```

Answer (score 0):

df[‘ADDRESS’] = np.where(df[‘ADDRESS’].isnull()), df[‘PURCHASE’], df[‘ADDRESS’])

Comment: That will fill in the address column with the purchase if there is a nan, not use the address above

Comment: This solution returns PURCHASE data if ADDRESS is null otherwise it returns ADDRESS. You could also replace “.isnull()” with “==‘NaN’”